# How to make a Docker environment variable value to get a random id

Tags: variables, docker, random, environment

I am looking to pass an environment variable which should get a `random id`.

**Something like below.**

```
ENV SERVICE_TAG= $uuid
```

In short, every time I run the container, I should get a random id for this environment variable inside the container.

> Can anyone please suggest the way forward?

Thanks and regards,

Prasanth.

Comment: What is the base image you are using?

Answer (score 7):

Add `uuidgen` package to the image. In case you are using alpine add

`RUN apk add --no-cache util-linux`

to the Dockerfile

Then in the entrypoint of your Dockerfile add

Below is a sample Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk add --no-cache util-linux
ENTRYPOINT export UUID=`uuidgen` && echo $UUIDFROM alpine:latest
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the environment variable from a `docker run -env` parameter generated `uuid` or `guid` from your shell, eg:

**bash:**

```
docker run --env SERVICE_TAG=$(uuidgen) yourimage
```

See more details at the official docker docs:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-environment-variables--e---env---env-file

Comment: docker run --env SERVICE_TAG=$(uuidgen) yourimage

This worked for me. Now I am struggling to make it fit in ECS Task definition. Everything I am keeing in json is turing into a string. Can someone help.

Comment: Not sure if you managed to solve that already, but I would submit the ECS question under a separate topic, because it is quite different from native docker experience.